# What is the shortcut for edge rotate or location in keymap list?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

With topology management a vital tool would be the rotation of edges and I would say that it would be even more vital to have a shortcut for clockwise and counter clockwise rotation. In 2.81, is there a shortcut for this and if not, where is the function located in the keymap settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just worked it out myself here, I added my own shortcut by right-clicking the function in the edge tools menu then assigning my own shortcut that way. I chose SHIFT + '<' for counter clockwise and SHIFT + '>' for clockwise.